# How to run an asp.net core website in windows server 2012 by kestrel?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, windows-server-2012-r2, kestrel

I have a challenge in run an Asp.net mvc core on windows server 2012,
I published my website by visual studio 2017 as a file system it runs correctly in my computer but on the remote system when I click on mysite.exe application kestrel runs and very fast closed.
Even I try that by change program.cs file in use of UseUrl("http://localhost:4000") and published that,It's worked correctly in my computer and in remote server but when I change specified url to "mysitename.com" at the program.cs the kestrel again very fast closed.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check for an exception in the event log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse proxy in IIS or Nginx or Apache.
A reverse proxy server receives HTTP requests from the Internet and forwards them to Kestrel after some preliminary handling.
for more information visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy)